# Creating a formula calculation from variables and coefficients in R

Tags: r, coefficients

I have two data frames. One with the main data and variables with values. And the second with coefficients, the variables they belong to, and the conditions in which they apply. I've done some searching on stackoverflow and most of the answers deal with combining this methodology with a linear model. My problem is a bit more simplistic than that (i think) and I'd love any feedback.

Below is some sample data of my two data frames.

Ideally i want a new column in "data" that is a calculation based on the variables in "data" multiplied by their coefficients in "coeff" with respect to the location. So in the example below, US only has sleep and book values where AU has all 3. I'd like a way to create a formula for each row in "data" that runs through a calculation of all the variables and coefficients.

I want to update by replacing the coefficient file and data file every year, so having it flexible to that criteria is a big plus. The variables by location will be very different in terms of how many adhere to what location.

```
data <- data.frame(Location = c("US", "UK", "AU","US"), Sleep = c(7, 4, 10, 11), Desk = c(0, 0, 1, 0), 
                   Book = c(11,0,19,3))
coeff<-data.frame(Location = c("US","US","UK","UK","AU","AU","AU"),
                  Variable = c("Sleep", "Book","Sleep", "Book","Sleep", "Book","Desk"),
                  Coefficient = c(.03,.11,.24,.004,.012,.10,.71))
```

for US in row 1 it will be (7*.030) + (11*.110)=1.42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this script helps (it uses data,table package):

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(Location = c("US", "UK", "AU","US"), Sleep = c(7, 4, 10, 11), Desk = c(0, 0, 1, 0), 
               Book = c(11,0,19,3))
coeff<-data.table(Location = c("US","US","Uk","Uk","AU","AU","AU"),
              Variable = c("Sleep", "Book","Sleep", "Book","Sleep", "Book","Desk"),
              Coefficient = c(.03,.11,.24,.004,.012,.10,.71))

data <- data[, order:=c(1:.N), by=Location]

d <- melt(data, id.vars=c('order','Location'), variable.name='Variable')

d <- merge(d,coeff, by=c('Location', 'Variable'), all=T)
d[is.na(d)] <- 0
d <- d[, result:=value*Coefficient,]
d <- d[,list(result=sum(result,na.rm=T)), by= list(order,Location)]

> head(d)
   order Location result
1:     1       AU   2.73
2:     1       UK   0.00
3:     1       US   1.42
4:     2       US   0.66
5:     0       Uk   0.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a nifty approach with the melt and ordering. I really appreciate it

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I have obtained so many times help from other participants, that it is a pleasure to be able to help another.